# The use of dup2 and execvp in c

Tags: c, execvp, dup2

I am writing a program which opens 2 files(file1 read only and file2 write only), it then opens a child process, replaces `stdin` with `file1` and `stdout` with `file2` using `dup2()` and then runs some shell command(`sort`,`cat`,`tr` or something of this sort). The text must come from `stdin(file1)` and be written to `stdout(file2)`. Here is the code that I have. It is not a complete code, it is just the function that child process calls.

```
void childProcess(int fd[],char* arguments[])
{
  int f1=atoi(arguments[0]); //gets file descriptor number of file1
  int f2=atoi(arguments[1]);  //fd number of file2
  dup2(fd[f1],0);    //changes stdin to file1
  dup2(fd[f2],1);    //changes stdout to file2

  char* myText[1024];


 //not sure how to get the content of stdin into myText

  char*execArgs[] = {"cat",myText,NULL};

  execvp("cat",execArgs);

}
```

So the 2 problems that I have are:  I am not sure how to get the entire `stdin(file1)` into `myText` and also, the program says:-

```
cat: no such file or directory.
```

Please help.

Comment: The contents of `myText` are undefined. When you pass that to `cat` it searches for a file with that name (which it most likely cannot find and might even crash).

Why do you want to copy the contents of `stdin` to `myText`? If you do the `execvp()` the called program will inherit the current `stdin` and in the case of `cat`, `tr` and friends read input from there.

Comment: @dhke You are correct except one thing: I cannot see how it could crash (unless there was a bug in `cat`)

Comment: @Ctx: Hmm. Since we are replacing the process image, `execvp()` needs to copy/touch/evaluate its arguments (e.g. copy into kernel space and then back). Since `myText` is not zero terminated, I see a possible segfault in the *calling* process (but probably `EINVAL` from `exec()`). `cat` does not even get invoked in that case.

Comment: @dhke Yes, `EFAULT` to be pedantic ;) But it should not crash in any case.

Comment: @Ctx You are [right there](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f5fbfb3a7c7b0a23f965) of course. Interestingly enough, segfaulting seems an equally valid option, as `EFAULT` isn't required to be reliable (see [SingleUnix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_03)). But of course this is far from the question, now ;).

Comment: @dhke You are right, I can say only for sure that under linux it would never segfault. Other Unices might behave different, seems.

Comment: regarding this line: `char* myText[1024];`.   It is declaring an array of 1024 pointers to char.  I suspect you actually want an array of 1024 characters: suggest: `char myText[1024];`  Notice the removal of the `*`.

Comment: the `cat` utility is expecting a parameter (or parameters) of pointers to file names.  The posted code is not passing any file name for the `cat` utility  rather it is passing a pointer to some random characters. (which, hopefully, contains a NUL char within the bounds of the array.

Comment: for flexibility, this line: `execvp("cat",execArgs);` would be better written as: `execvp( execArgs[0], execArgs );`

Comment: one way to get 'stdin' into the 'text[]' array: `fgets( text, sizeof(text), stdin);`

Comment: while a `exec??()` rarely fails, that eventuality should always be allowed for in the code,  so the call to `execvp()` should always be followed by: `perror( "execvp failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`